# if none observe me -- why not "if none observes me"?

Tags: conditional-constructions, verb-forms

That's a famous quote from Franz Kafka.

> **if none observe me**, I have to observe myself all the closer.

Comment: Remember that Kafka wrote in German,  and this is probably a translation, showing the difficulty of translating the German *keiner* in certain situations. It's not something you'd be likely to see written by a native English speaker.

Comment: Yes. *If none observe me* is a poetic/old-fashioned way of talking. A modern day equivalent would probably be *if no one observes me*, which would take the singular verb.

Comment: And the advantage in using *none* is that the word *observe* is used in both halves of the sentence, creating a nice symmetry. It may have been a stylistic choice as much as anything.

Comment: The translation may reflects the "subjunctive inversion" in the original German: "Unentrinnbare Verpflichtung zur Selbstbeobachtung: Werde ich von jemandem andern beobachtet, muß ich mich natürlich auch beobachten, **werde** ich von niemandem sonst beobachtet, muß ich mich um so genauer beobachten."
—[Tagebücher 1910-1923](http://gutenberg.spiegel.de/buch/tagebucher-1910-1923-162/13), 1921, 7. November

Comment: StoneyB, I'm not familiar with German, but are you saying that "If none observe me" is closer to the original German than "If no one observes me"? Just asking out of interest.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

*None* can be singular or plural, depending on what it is referring to.

Here it is referring to "the people". A fuller reading of the quote might be:

> if none **of the people** observe me, I have to observe myself all the closer.

*The people* is plural, and so takes the plural verb *observe*.

It should be pointed out that it's not so much about a hard-and-fast rule but about clarity. If you’re wanting to emphasise “not any amongst many” as in the above example then you should use the plural to make this emphasis clear. There’s a good discussion of *notional agreement* here http://dictionary.reference.com/help/faq/language/g11.html

ODO's usage section isn't quite as explicit, but does mention it depends on the emphasis needed http://oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/none

Comment: This is an interesting question. If I say "None of the pencils is red," "pencils" is plural but "none" is singular. Why?

Comment: *pencils* is plural, so you should use the plural *are*. You should say, "None of the pencils are red".

Comment: @GrahamNicol Any reference for that?

Comment: It’s not so much about a hard-and-fast rule but about clarity. If you’re wanting to emphasise “not any amongst many” as in the above examples then you should use the plural to make this emphasis clear. There’s a good discussion of *notional agreement* here http://dictionary.reference.com/help/faq/language/g11.html

Comment: ODO's *usage* section isn't quite as explicit, but they do mention it depends on the emphasis needed http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/none

Comment: In other words, you can say "None of the pencils *is* red." to emphasize the singularity of each individual pencil, or "None of the pencils *are* red." to emphasize the entire set.

Comment: @GrahamNicol Why are you so sure that *none* in the quote refers to "the people"?

Comment: I think it's obvious from the context he's talking about other people not observing him - but it doesn't much matter for the purposes of grammar whether it's "the people" or "blue rhinoceroses on Mars".

Comment: @GrahamNicol ***pencils is plural, so you should use the plural are. You should say, "None of the pencils are red".***. No, this is completely untrue!

Comment: I probably should have said "You can say..." rather than you "You should...". It does depend on what you want to emphasise, as I said a few lines up, but you can't edit answers.

Answer (score 8):

Even though some disagree, *none* can have a plural meaning. [For instance](http://grammarist.com/spelling/none-are-or-none-is/):

> (…) while the police found 170,425 images, **none were** classed as indecent. ([The Telegraph](http://www.telegraph.co.uk/news/uknews/crime/11261474/Paedophile-doctor-abused-child-cancer-patients-while-their-parents-were-in-the-room.html).)

So we could interpret *none* in *if none observe me* as plural. However there is nothing in the [fuller quotation](https://books.google.pt/books?id=He3aRBskI_0C&pg=PA68&lpg=PA68&dq=%22if%20none%20observe%20me%22&source=bl&ots=-7pDYBZ99N&sig=LeRuGq0taCiWk_nEuaeVnDEj5WM&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0CCQQ6AEwAWoVChMIkp7q4sG8yAIVzNUaCh3cNwLX#v=onepage&q=%22if%20none%20observe%20me%22&f=false) to force on us that reading of *none*:

> This inescapable duty to observe oneself: if someone else is observing me, naturally I have to observe myself too; if none observe me, I have to observe myself all the closer. (Franz Kafka, November 7, 1921.)

Now, in my admittedly limited research, all plural ‘*nones*’ I have found referred to a plural noun in the preceding clause, as the 170,425 images in the example above, or were part of expressions such as *none of them*. This is not the case in the Kafka quotation.

So, we should consider another possibilty. *If none observe me* may be an old-fashioned use of [the present subjunctive](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/English_subjunctive#Use_of_the_present_subjunctive) in conditional sentences ([see also here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/English_conditional_sentences#Zero_conditional)), as in:

> If he be found guilty he shall be hung.

With *observe*, whether *none* be singular or plural, the same structure is:

> If none observe me I have to observe myself all the closer.

Answer (score 3):

The subject is **None** which can be both singular and plural. It's a  misconception that it is always singular.

> if none observe me, I have to observe myself all the closer.

Here, **none** is plural, so it took a plural form of verb **Observe.**

In the next part of the quote, **to observe** is infinitive. When you use an infinitive verb, the “to” is a part of the verb, and the verb is always just the verb. It’s not conjugated in anyway `– no -ed, no -ing, no -s on the end.`

Comment: @Micah oh! thanks for telling. I am still a learner.

Comment: @Micah corrected it.

Answer (score 2):

Multiple answers have pointed to "none" as being optionally singular or plural. While we can't really say for sure *why* the author (or rather, translator from Kafka's German to English) chose this phrasing, I have a different theory.

**It is the subjunctive mood.**

The subjunctive mood is used (among other things) to express hypothetical scenarios, such as ones following an "if". In English, in the present tense, the subjunctive has the same form as the infinitive (without "to").

> If he **be** willing...
>
> If the dog **steal** my bacon...
>
> If none **observe** me...

In modern usage, the subjunctive is very rare, especially the present subjunctive. (The past subjunctive, using "were", is slightly more common.)

Further reading: [Wikipedia, "English subjunctive"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/English_subjunctive)

---

Incidentally, I don't agree with those other answers that say "none" can be singular or plural. I would always take "none" to be plural. But that might be dialect-specific, and someone who has a good book on grammar handy can speak more authoritatively than I can.

Comment: Do you mean "I would always take 'none' to be *singular*"? That's what I was expecting from from what you had written before.

Comment: @Jacinto: Nope. I would say "none *are* suitable", not "none *is* suitable".

Comment: I thought you meant otherwise, because if none is plurar is there a reason to think *none observe* is subjunctive, given the rare use of the subjunctive?

Comment: @Jacinto: It fits the context. Most verbs look identical in the present plural and in the subjunctive, but that doesn't mean we always have to interpret a sentence as using the present plural (if valid) rather than the subjunctive. And in this case, identifying it as the subjunctive avoids the singular/plural status of "none" entirely. Still, you could argue that present plural is a *simpler* explanation, and therefore better (applying Occam's Razor)...

Comment: Quite so. Not that this will shed much light on the present question, but if you like statistics you may look at [*to be*, where subjunctive and indicative are different](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=none+are%2Cnone+is&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cnone%20are%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cnone%20is%3B%2Cc0)