# How do I know which conjugation of a verb to use?

Tags: verb-forms, subject-verb-agreement

I have noticed on this site that some say that if there is a singular subject, we use a plural verb.

Example: "Run" is a verb. 3rd person singular is "runs".

> You run.
>
> I run.
>
> He runs.
>
> They run (Why not "runs"?)

Why didn't we use plural form of verb "runs" since the subject is plural?

MamtaD says in [her answer](https://ell.stackexchange.com/a/71208/25493) that

> **does** is the right word to use here and not **do** because your verb has to agree with the subject.

i.e. the subject *ring* is singular and so the verb should be singular.

Why these are acceptable:

> I do
> You do
> They do

They, again, is plural subject, so why it is not "they does"?

So, if a subject is singular, we use plural verb?
as said by Usernew [in his/her answer](https://ell.stackexchange.com/a/70616/25493)

> Here, **none** is plural, so it took a singular form of verb **Observe**.

Comment: "They" is *plural* pronoun. "Does" is a 3rd person *singular* form. 3rd person *plural* is "do".

Comment: @Mrstupid, See my earlier answer, it says the **verb has to agree with the subject**.  *they runs* is incorrect because the verb and subject **do not match**. For singular, you will use **runs** and for plural, *run*. Please read [this article here](http://www.towson.edu/ows/sub-verb.htm).

Comment: It will all seem less odd if you study some German and its declensions, and understand that modern English is the descendant of an early medieval Germanic dialect, which was later influenced  in the 11th century, with the Norman Conquest, by a form of French. Some, but not all, of the declensions marking verb number coalesced over the ten centuries since then.

Comment: I think your confusion here comes from the difference between nouns and verbs. You only make nouns plural by adding an "s" - this is not the case for verbs (the way most - but not quite all - verbs are conjugated, pretty much all the forms are the same apart from the third person singular). So while "apples" is the plural of "apple", "runs" is *not* the plural form of "to run". [which of course gets more complicated with your example of 'ring' - if a ring (noun) makes a loud noise, "the *ring* **rings**", but "the *rings* **ring**" (italic noun, bold verb in both)]

Comment: I'm currently studying French & realizing that when you pluralize the noun, *everything* gets pluralized: the verb, the adjectives... That's not the case in English. "Young" stays the same whether it's "boy" or "boys", E.G. "The young boy was running", "The young boys were running", and so on.

Comment: @G.Ann-SonarSourceTeam In German it takes yet another leap, as the adjective endings depend on the gender of the noun (of which there are three + plural), the case (nominative/accusative/dative/genitive), and whether the article referring to the noun is definite or indefinite. http://www.lsa.umich.edu/german/hmr/Grammatik/Adjektive/Adjektivendungen.html#summary For all its weird foibles, at least English grammar is pretty simple for that kind of thing.

Comment: @JezW I drew a contrast with French only because it has a similar system to what the OP was expecting.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**Main Points**

- An **S** on the end of a verb doesn't make it plural like it does for nouns
- We use the term "plural verbs", but *verbs aren't plural themselves*. Rather, they are changed based on whether or not the noun they are paired with is plural.

---

**Clearing the Confusion**

> > they run (why not runs?)
>
> Why didn't we use plural form of verb "runs" since the subject is plural?

I think you are getting confused by the **s** on the end of the verbs. **S** is only used to make **nouns** plural. The **s** on the end of some verbs is coincidental.

We use the term "plural verbs", but *verbs aren't plural themselves*. Rather, they are changed based on whether or not the noun they are paired with is plural.

---

**More Information**

Verbs are "conjugated" when we used them. That means we take the basic "infinitive" form of a verb and change it slightly to suit two (main) things.

We change its ***tense* - when the action took place** and we change it depending on **who/what** the action applies to. The "who/what" takes in to account whether or not the speaker is included and how many people or things are being spoken about.

For most verbs, there is a pattern you can apply. Some verbs are irregular and you just have to learn them. I've given examples for a few verbs for two tenses below:

**[Present Simple Tense](http://www.englishpage.com/verbpage/simplepresent.html)**

This action takes place in the present or we are describing something that happens regularly.

```
              Who/What       Verb (Run)   Verb (eat)   Verb (be - irregular)
----------------------------------------------------------------------------

Singular
1st Person     I              run          eat            am

2nd Person     You            run          eat            are

3rd Person     He/She/It      runs         eats           is

Plural    
1st Person     We             run          eat            are

2st Person     ------(Always the same as 2nd Person Singular)-------

3rd Person     They           run          eat            are
```

Just adding an **s** (or sometimes *es*) to 3rd person plural is the pattern for a lot of verbs.

---

**[Simple Past Tense](http://www.englishpage.com/verbpage/simplepast.html)**

This action took place in the past. It has already finished.

```
              Who/What       Verb (Run)   Verb (eat)   Verb (be - irregular)
----------------------------------------------------------------------------

Singular
1st Person     I              ran          ate            was

2nd Person     You            ran          ate            were

3rd Person     He/She/It      ran          ate            was

Plural    
1st Person     We             ran          ate            were

2st Person     ------(Always the same as 2nd Person Singular)-------

3rd Person     They           ran          ate            were
```

A lot of verbs just add **-ed**, for past tense but a lot don't!

I can't think of a common pattern for learning the past form of a verb, but the regular verbs tend to use the same work for all people.

Some examples:

```
Infinitive               = Past
================================
run                      = ran  
eat                      = ate  
drink                    = drank
read (pronounced "reed") = read (pronounced "red") 
write                    = wrote
kneel                    = knelt 
see                      = saw
tell                     = told

Some that do use -ed

need                     = needed
walk                     = walked
spell                    = spelled (but also spelt)
```

---

Comment: "spell" is not the best example of a "regular" past because its past tense is often written "[spelt](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/spell?q=spell)"